# Can not Perform Function on New Window Opened with Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, tabs, bookmarklet

I like to create a simple bookmarklet which:

1. opens a specific website in a new tab (window)
2. and submits a string to the site's search field.

I succeed in doing 1 and 2 separately, but when putting them together
**the tab opens without the search field receiving any input.**

*I have little idea what I am doing wrong here.
What solution can you suggest?*

**My code:**

```
(function(foo){   

    // 1.) open new tab/window
    var myWindow = window.open('http://www.fakespot.com/', '_blank');    
    myWindow.focus();

    // 2.) input + click submit button   
    document.getElementById("url").value = "test input";
    document.getElementsByName("commit")[0].click();   
})('foo')
```

**Does not work either:**

```
    ...
    myWindow.document.getElementById("url").value = link;
    myWindow.document.getElementsByName("commit")[0].click();
    ...
```

Transform JavaScript into bookmarklet here:
http://chriszarate.github.io/bookmarkleter/

Comment: You are going to need to use something like TaperMonkey

Comment: Why does Javascript let us down here? Where is the actual breaking point?

Comment: Problem is bookmarklet code that you are running is not work on the new window. And with the same origin policy, you would need to be on the website first, before clicking the bookmark to be able to make the code work. If that is right, than you need to add code to wait for the window to load, than you are able to reference the form elements inside of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you are trying to do using HTML5 localStorage. Here is an example of how it works. Open the attached fiddle in 2 separate tabs and pass messages between them!

// HTML (Used only for testing)

```
<!-- This is your parent window -->
<input type="text" id="message1" />
<button type="button" value="Send Message" onclick="updateStorageEvent()">Send Message</button>

<!-- This would be your theoretical second window -->
<!-- Open this fiddle in a second tab then send messages to see the results in the other window-->
<p id="messageReceived"></p>
```

// JS

```
// Parent Window
var data = document.getElementById('message1');

function updateStorageEvent() {
    localStorage.setItem('storage-event', data.value);
}

// Target Window
var output = document.getElementById('messageReceived');

window.addEventListener('storage', function (event) {
  output.innerHTML = event.newValue;
});
```

Here is the link to a fiddle showing this working. Right click the link and select open in new tab. Do this twice and you can pass messages between them.
http://jsfiddle.net/wpwelch/khje9Lh3/2/

Comment: THX, buzzsaw! I will need about three days learning to implement this.

Comment: I tried but, I can not see how using HTML5 localStorage would bypass the origin policy problem. Your proposed solution would require to open the target site manually, which defies the very purpose of the bookmarklet I like to code. Or is my implementation wrong?